Loading variables using dynamic sql. Give nvarchar to float error, or loads null in sql statement
I am trying to load a table value into a variable.   I am doing it dynamically because that table could have 1-5 variables to load.  I either get a null value in my select statement or I get error converting nvarchar to float.  Or I get fields don't exist because I have an if statement on what to do if there are 2, 3, 4, and 5 variables, but those fields don't exist in the table all the time, so it doesn't like that version either.   Currently the balance1 table has 1 row with total, adjfield1, adfield2.  and the entry looks like this  Total      27995.2200000031        27995.2200000031
I am just wanting to load the first value in tot_adjfield1, then 2nd value in tot_adjfield2 and so on if there are more in that table.   This time there are only 2 but there could be up to 5.
Thank you very much for any help at all!
This one gives error converting nvarchar to float
Declare @tot_adjfield1 float
Declare @sqltext4b varchar(100)

set @sqltext4b = N'SELECT ' + @tot_adjfield1 + '= bal_adjfield1 FROM valtst.balance1'
select @sqltext4b
exec(@sqltext4b)

This one gives me null in my @sqltext4b statement
Declare @tot_adjfield1 float
Declare @sqltext4b varchar(100)

set @sqltext4b = N'SELECT ' + cast(@tot_adjfield1 as varchar(20)) + '= bal_adjfield1 FROM valtst.balance1'
select @sqltext4b
exec(@sqltext4b)

I tried this one to not have to use dynamic sql, but it gives me errors because bal_adjfiedl3 doesn't exist this time
If @numfields = 1
     BEGIN 
        select @tot_adjfield1  = bal_adjfield1  from valtst.balance1               

if @numfields = 2             
     BEGIN
        select  @tot_adjfield1  = bal_adjfield1, @tot_adjfield2  = bal_adjfield2 from valtst.balance1                
     END

if @numfields = 3             
     BEGIN
        select @tot_adjfield1 =bal_adjfield1, @tot_adjfield2 =bal_adjfield2, @tot_adjfield3 =bal_adjfield3  from valtst.balance1
     END


I also tried this, but got the same converting error which I wonder if I get that fixed if I will have the same field doesn't exist issue.
